# Which is better? Data URL scheme or image links for displaying image?

Tags: html, css, image, data-url

I am a bit confused about this. For displaying images in my HTML page, embedding image code is good in HTML img tag (using Data URL technique) or giving a link to that image file will be more better (the traditional way)? If anyone can tell me the advantages and disadvantages of both of them in a comparative manner than it will be a great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Data URL embedding**:

- ↑ Fewer HTTP requests to load the page;
- ↓ Super-long code lines with not-tiny images;
- ↓ Hard (very hard) to maintain (think when you need to replace images);
- ↓ IE 6 and 7 do not support it.

**Image link**:

- ↑ Easy to maintain (you just have to replace the file);
- ↑ Cached independently of the HTML;
- ↑ Code is conciser;
- ↑ Supported in all versions of IE;
- ↓ More HTTP requests to load the page.

In general, I suggest to use links for larger images (photo, layout elements, big icons) and for images that can change over time. Use Data URL only for very small icons.

I have to say you can avoid the first two Data URL problems (long code and maintainable) generating Data URL from a physical image file, using a server-side language (PHP for example) for encoding.

Comment: thanks @lorenzo-s. that's what I was asking for